# Селектор для двух классов на одном узле

Tags: css, css-selectors

Допустим у нас есть классы `.red` и `.blue`, как выбрать только тот элемент где на одном узле сразу два этих класса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так

```
.red.blue { ваши стили }
```